# Ruby on Rails - Update collection_select while filling out the form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, simple-form

My application works as I have **4 records** with same fields (`:name`, `:family_with`) in my form already that users needs to fill out with the `:name`.

*(PS: I am using nested forms and cocoon gem)*.

*Here is my form:*

```
= f.simple_fields_for :families do |family|
   = f.text_field :name
   = f.collection_select :family_with, Family.where(family_id: @family), :id, :name, {include_blank: "Choose a name"}
```

What I am looking for is, how can I update `collection_select :family_with` every time a `f.text_field :name` is fill, so my `collection_select :family_with` can populate the **name**'s that has been inserted in each `= f.text_field :name`.

I have read that I could do it with ajax or jQuery but would appreciate any code solution.

Comment: Since you want the `family_with` input to dynamically update based on `text_field` value, you would have to either send AJAX or use other javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it this?

```
= f.collection_select :family_with, Family.all.where(family_id: @family), :id, :name, {include_blank: "Choose a name"},selected: f.object.family_with
```

Comment: Tnx, No I dont want to show the `selected`. I want to update the `collection_select` while user is inserting `name` in same form/page.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you consider a "code solution" but if you mean through ruby/rails then you have to at least submit the form to get any updates in the collection_select

When I had to do something with dependent/dynamic select menus this page was very useful for me (involves jQuery): http://blog.kate-travers.com/dynamic-duos-dependent-select-with-jquery-and-rails/